# Cant connect with cloud_sql_proxy over tcp

Tags: google-cloud-sql

I created a Cloud SQL instance and am trying to connect from my laptop running OSX El Capitan.

I followed the [instructions for creating a proxy](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/sql-proxy) to run the proxy. I am able to connect if I use a socket file as follows:

```
sudo ./cloud_sql_proxy -dir=/cloudsql -instances=my-project:us-central1:mysql-instance -credential_file=mycredentials.json

mysql -u root -p -S /cloudsql/my-project:us-central1:mysql-instance
```

Now I'd like to connect to the Cloud SQL instance from a local python application. So I tried creating the proxy over tcp using `=tcp:3306` and testing using the mysql client as follows:

```
sudo ./cloud_sql_proxy -dir=/cloudsql -instances=my-project:us-central1:mysql-instance=tcp:3306 -credential_file=/web/visi/api/resources/keys/visi-staging-ec040759d57a.json

mysql -u root --host 127.0.0.1 --password
```

But Im getting this error:

> 2016/04/06 23:09:58 Got a connection for
>   "my-project:us-central1:mysql-instance" 2016/04/06 23:09:59
>   to "my-project:us-central1:mysql-instance" via
>   111.111.111.111:3307: read tcp 127.0.0.1:3306->127.0.0.1:49518: use of closed network connection ERROR 2026 (HY000): SSL connection error:
>   error:00000005:lib(0):func(0):DH lib

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try specifying --skip-ssl as an option to your mysql client.

We have a fix for this in progress and should be rolled out in the near future.

The reason this happens is that we reject connections over the proxy that request MySQL SSL. The connection between the proxy and Cloud SQL is already done over SSL so there's no need to use SSL at the MySQL level.

Comment: Thanks. That works but I got a warn saying `--skip-ssl` is deprecated. This command worked for me: `mysql -u root --port 3306 --host 127.0.0.1 --ssl-mode=DISABLED`